# How to display view model validation for a view that has multiple forms on it?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I'm trying to better understand how to properly structure my ASP.NET MVC code to handle a situation where a single view contains multiple forms. I feel that it makes sense to submit the forms to their own action methods, so that each form can benefit from its own view model parameter binding and validation, and to avoid putting all form parameters into 1 larger, monolithic view model.

I'm trying to code this pattern, but I can't seem to tie the loose ends together.

I've written some example action methods below, along with example view model classes, that I think demonstrate what I'm trying to achieve. Lets say that I've got an `Item` `Detail` action method and view. On this `Detail` view, I've got two forms - one that creates a new `Comment` and another that creates a new `Note`. Both `Comment` and `Note` forms `POST` to their own action methods - `DetailNewComment` and `DetailNewNote`.

On success, these `POST` handler action methods work just fine. On an invalid model state though, I return `View(model)` so that I can display the issues on the original `Detail` view. This tries to render a view named `Brief` though, instead of `Detail`. If I use the overloaded `View` call that allows me to specify which view to render, then now I have issues with the different view model classes that I'm using. The specific view model classes now no longer work with the original `DetailViewModel`.

I get the feeling that I'm doing this completely wrong. How am I supposed to be handling this scenario with multiple forms? Thanks!

```
public ActionResult Detail(int id)
{
  var model = new ItemDetailViewModel
  {
    Item = ItemRepository.Get(id)
  };

  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DetailNewComment(int id, ItemDetailNewCommentViewModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(model);
  }

  var comment = CommentRepository.Insert(new Comment
  {
    Text = model.Text
  });

  return RedirecToAction("Detail", new { id = id; });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DetailNewNote(int id, ItemDetailNewNoteViewModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return View(model);
  }

  var note = NoteRepository.Insert(new Note
  {
    Text = model.Text
  });

  return RedirectToAction("Detail", new { id = id; });
}
```

... with view models something like ...

```
public class ItemDetailViewModel
{
  public Item Item { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDetailNewCommentViewModel
{
  public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class ItemDetailNewNoteViewModel
{
  public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case I'd recommend to have a master model for example your 
`ItemDetailViewModel` class to which you'll add a property for each sub-model

```
public class ItemDetailViewModel
{
  public Item Item { get; set; }
  public ItemDetailNewCommentViewModel NewCommentModel {get;set;}
  public ItemDetailNewNoteViewModel NoteModel {get;set;}
}
```

Your Detail view will be the master view and the other two will be partial views.
Master view will receive an instance of ItemDetailViewModel as model and inside view you will render your partials by passing Model.NewCommentModel and Model.NoteModel as their corresponding models. For being able to use separate actions for each form, instead of regular forms you can use ajax forms, thus you will send to the server only relevant information without altering the rest of the master view.

Answer (score 0):

The chief problem here is what happens when the user messes up and their post doesn't pass validation server-side. If you choose to take them to a page where just the one form is presented, then you can post to a different action, but if you want both forms re-displayed, then they both should point to the same action.

Really, you just have to make a choice. I've seen sites handle it both ways. Personally, I prefer to re-display the original form, which means handling both forms in the same action. It *can* lead to bloat, but you can factor out a lot of logic from the action such that you end up with mostly just a branch depending on which form was submitted.